# Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = handle) : URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL

Tags: r, curl, rvest

I have this function that won't run. The command inside of the code works when it is applied on it's own but when I run it in this lapply function it errors out. I have tried updating my Curl libraries etc... No idea why it's happening.

```
    library(curl)
    ##dataframe looks like this as factor list: x = "http://google.com" 
    funk <- function(x) {
            read_html(x) %>% html_node("title") %>% html_text 
    }
    df$titles<-lapply(df$urls,funk)

    Error: 'Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = handle) : 
    URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL
    ' does not exist in current working directory ('/Users/Home/').
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Updated. The dataframe is a list of URLs like the example above as factor list.

Comment: Coerce to character? It's impossible to diagnose without seeing the URLs.

Comment: @alistaire yeah tried as.character(df$urls) inside the lapply, and no luck

Answer (score 0):

The function works inside `lapply`:

```
df <- data.frame(urls=c("http://google.com", "http://ytcracker.com"), stringsAsFactors = F)
funk <- function(x) {
  read_html(x) %>% html_node("title") %>% html_text 
}

lapply(df$urls, funk)
```

> ```
> [[1]]
> [1] "Google"
>
> [[2]]
> [1] "ytOS/2014"
> ```

```
df$titles <- lapply(df$urls, funk)
df
```

> ```
>                   urls    titles
> 1    http://google.com    Google
> 2 http://ytcracker.com ytOS/2014
> ```

So the problem must be with the non-reproducible part of your question, which would be the data frame (please `dput()` your data in R questions in the future -- check out the R tag description for more info).

Specifically, the error message implies the problem is probably how you specified the URL's within that data frame.

Even more specifically, when you get the error saying

> ```
> ' does not exist in current working directory ('/Users/Home/').
> ```

that almost always means you didn't qualify the domain with `http://` or `https://`, etc.